# difference between cart getItemsCount() and getSummaryCount()

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am displaying the total items present in the cart at header. 
I am able to display the count of items.

But I am bit confused between two methods of cart

```
1. Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount()
2. Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
```

For me 1st one returns 1 item in cart and 2nd one returns 6 items in cart, Which is correct one and what is the difference these two functions..

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount() -- return shopping cart items count means how many sku add to shopping cart.
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount() -- return shopping cart items summary (suppose you add sku1 6 qty and sku2 3 qty = total 9 qty return)
```

Comment: Note: it's getItemCount() not getItemsCount() on CE 1.9.2 for Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar. getItemsCount() will fail silently (returning empty string) and can cause bugs due to this behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

This way getItemsCount will work:

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
```

If not then try adding this above the getItemsCount line:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
```

And For Summary Count:

```
$count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason you were downvoted is that the OP was asking what the difference between the two is, not the syntax for using them.