# Double the Shipping Charges for certain items count at the cart

Tags: checkout, shipping

I wish to modify the shipping cost Double if they add more than 5 items at the cart.

```
class ChangeShipping_MyCarrier_Model_Carrier extends
    Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract implements
    Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    protected function _getStandardShippingRate()
    {
        $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $rate->setMethod('standand');
        $rate->setMethodTitle('Standard');

        $items_count = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
        if ($items_count > 6) {
            $rate->setPrice(19.99);
        } else {
            $rate->setPrice(9.99);
        }
        $rate->setCost(0);
        return $rate;
    }
}
```

This function executes flawless without IF condition but shows error then.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: I suggest you add a Mage::log($items_count) you might find that the count isnt actually what you are thinking. Ie if you add a configurable product, is it giving you 1 or 2? (simple+configurable). Moreover, do you want qty to be factored in? See this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23491/difference-between-cart-getitemscount-and-getsummarycount

Answer (score 2):

In the carrier model please use `$request` object, and not the `$cart` object, as we can create the order from admin, API and other sources. See example here:

`\app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php`

You need is to modify the `collectRates` based on you logic:

```
...
if ($request->getPackageQty() > 6) { // modify price }
...
```